# Runtime error "undefined symbol g_malloc0_n" - but only on old Debian5

Tags: linux, debian, gtk, loader

We have a legacy Linux application, written in C, using GTK.

- We compile it on Ubuntu14/32-bit, we can also launch it
- In production, we run it on Debian10/32-bit

We have some very old hosts, which runs Debian 5. The old version of the application runs on Debian 5, but when we compile a new one, we got a runtime message:

```
.../bin/gui: symbol lookup error: .../lib/libmkt.so: undefined symbol: g_malloc0_n
```

It's strange, because `nm` finds it:

```
$ nm .../lib/libmkt.so | grep g_malloc
     U g_malloc0
     U g_malloc0_n
```

Also the application has a good reference entry to the library:

```
$  ldd .../bin/gui | grep libmkt
     libmkt.so => .../lib/libmkt.so (0xb7257000)
```

This is happening only on the old machine with Debian 5:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux kiosk 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Mon Aug 30 07:01:57 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

On the new machine, with Debian 10, the application starts:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux kiosk 4.19.0-17-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-1 (2021-06-10) i686 GNU/Linux
```

The developer machine with Ubuntu14, the application starts:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-build-server 4.4.0-142-generic #168~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP 
Sat Jan 19 11:28:33 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

We start the application with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.../lib .../bin/gui`, we have a bunch of `.so` files in the `.../lib` directory, including the `.../lib/libmkt.so`, which indicates the error.

My hint is that the compiler uses some feature for `libmkt.so`, which the 2.6 kernel does not like, but I haven't found such issue on the internet.

UPDATE: `.../lib/libmkt.so` does not contain the missing `g_malloc0_n` symbol, but it refers to the GTK library, which does. What should I do in order to find such second-hop symbols?